# Golf handicap calculator app not outputting

Tags: python, kivy

this is my first time ever creating an app. I am trying to create a golf handicap calculator that will allow 4 players to enter their names and handicap and then the app will calculate the handicap.

What I have so far allows me to input that data however after inputting the data it says there are no scorecards available inside of kivy. I'm not quite sure what is happening here and would greatly appreciate any help that you may offer. Thank you :)

This is what I have so far.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import json


class GolfScorecardApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Load existing data from file
        self.load_data()

        # Main layout
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10)

        # Title label
        title_label = Label(text="Golf Scorecard App", font_size=24, size_hint=(1, 0.1))
        layout.add_widget(title_label)

        # Player input layout
        player_input_layout = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=10, size_hint=(1, 0.5))

        # Player name inputs
        self.player_name_inputs = []
        for i in range(4):
            player_name_input = TextInput(hint_text='Enter player name')
            self.player_name_inputs.append(player_name_input)
            player_input_layout.add_widget(Label(text=f"Player {i+1} Name:"))
            player_input_layout.add_widget(player_name_input)

        # Player handicap inputs
        self.player_handicap_inputs = []
        for i in range(4):
            player_handicap_input = TextInput(hint_text='Enter player handicap')
            self.player_handicap_inputs.append(player_handicap_input)
            player_input_layout.add_widget(Label(text=f"Player {i+1} Handicap:"))
            player_input_layout.add_widget(player_handicap_input)

        layout.add_widget(player_input_layout)

        # Add players button
        add_player_button = Button(text='Add Players', size_hint=(1, 0.1))
        add_player_button.bind(on_release=self.add_player)
        layout.add_widget(add_player_button)

        # Create game button
        create_game_button = Button(text='Create Game', size_hint=(1, 0.1))
        create_game_button.bind(on_release=self.create_game)
        layout.add_widget(create_game_button)

        # Scrollable player list
        self.players_scroll_view = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 0.2))

        # Player list layout
        self.players_layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None, height=100)

        self.players_scroll_view.add_widget(self.players_layout)
        layout.add_widget(self.players_scroll_view)

        # Result label
        self.result_label = Label(text='', size_hint=(1, 0.2), valign='top')
        layout.add_widget(self.result_label)

        return layout

    def load_data(self):
        try:
            # Load existing data from file
            with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
                self.data = json.load(file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # If file doesn't exist, initialize with empty data and sample scorecards
            self.data = {'scorecards': [], 'players': []}
            self.data['scorecards'] = [
                {'name': 'Scorecard 1',
                 'holes': [{'number': 1, 'par': 4}, {'number': 2, 'par': 3}, {'number': 3, 'par': 5}], 'slope': 72},
                {'name': 'Scorecard 2',
                 'holes': [{'number': 1, 'par': 4}, {'number': 2, 'par': 3}, {'number': 3, 'par': 5}], 'slope': 72}
            ]

    def save_data(self):
        # Save data to file
        with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(self.data, file)

    def add_player(self, instance):
        # Get player names and handicaps from input
        players = []
        for i in range(4):
            name = self.player_name_inputs[i].text
            handicap = self.player_handicap_inputs[i].text

            if name and handicap and handicap.isdigit():
                player = {'name': name, 'handicap': int(handicap)}
                players.append(player)

        # Add players to data
        if players:
            self.data['players'].extend(players)

            # Update the player list display
            self.update_player_list()

        # Clear input fields
        for i in range(4):
            self.player_name_inputs[i].text = ''
            self.player_handicap_inputs[i].text = ''

        # Save data
        self.save_data()

    def create_game(self, instance):
        # Select players for the game
        players = self.select_players()
        if len(players) < 4:
            self.result_label.text = "Select at least 4 players."
            return

        # Select a scorecard
        self.selected_players = players
        self.select_scorecard()  # Call the select_scorecard method

    def select_scorecard(self):
        scorecards = self.data['scorecards']
        if not scorecards:
            self.result_label.text = "No scorecards available."
            return None

        dropdown = DropDown()
        for scorecard in scorecards:
            btn = Button(text=scorecard['name'], size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.on_scorecard_select(btn.text))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        main_button = Button(text='Select Scorecard', size_hint=(1, None), height=44)
        main_button.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)
        layout.add_widget(main_button)
        dropdown.bind(on_select=self.on_scorecard_select)

        # Replace the current layout with the scorecard selection layout
        self.root.clear_widgets()
        self.root.add_widget(layout)

    def on_scorecard_select(self, value):
        # Retrieve the selected scorecard object based on the value
        selected_scorecard = None
        for scorecard in self.data['scorecards']:
            if scorecard['name'] == value:
                selected_scorecard = scorecard
                break

        if selected_scorecard:
            # Calculate extra strokes for each player on each hole
            game_handicap = sum(player['handicap'] for player in self.selected_players) // 4
            game_results = self.calculate_game_results(selected_scorecard, self.selected_players, game_handicap)

            # Display the game results in the result label
            self.display_results(game_results)

            # Return to the main layout
            self.root.clear_widgets()
            self.root.add_widget(self.build())

            # Reset the selected players
            self.selected_players = []
        else:
            # Display an error message if no scorecards are available
            self.result_label.text = "No scorecards available."

            # Return to the main layout
            self.root.clear_widgets()
            self.root.add_widget(self.build())

            # Reset the selected players
            self.selected_players = []

    def select_players(self):
        players = self.data['players']
        if not players:
            self.result_label.text = "No players available."
            return []

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)
        checkboxes = []

        for player in players:
            checkbox = CheckBox(active=False, size_hint=(1, None), height=44)
            checkbox.player = player  # Attach the player object to the checkbox
            checkboxes.append(checkbox)
            layout.add_widget(checkbox)

        select_button = Button(text='Select Players', size_hint=(1, None), height=44)
        select_button.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.on_player_select(checkboxes))

        layout.add_widget(select_button)

        # Display the list of players in the result label
        player_names = [player['name'] for player in players]
        self.result_label.text = f"Available Players: {', '.join(player_names)}"

        # Return the selected players instead of the layout
        return checkboxes

    def on_player_select(self, checkboxes):
        selected_players = []
        for checkbox in checkboxes:
            if checkbox.active:
                selected_players.append(checkbox.player)

        return selected_players

    def calculate_game_results(self, scorecard, players, game_handicap):
        game_results = {}
        for player in players:
            player_name = player['name']
            player_handicap = int(player['handicap'])
            extra_strokes = []
            for hole in scorecard['holes']:
                hole_number = hole['number']
                hole_par = hole['par']
                extra_strokes_count = max(0, hole_par + player_handicap - scorecard['slope'] + game_handicap)
                extra_strokes.append(extra_strokes_count)
            game_results[player_name] = extra_strokes
        return game_results

    def display_results(self, game_results):
        result_text = ""
        for player, extra_strokes in game_results.items():
            result_text += f"{player}: {extra_strokes}\n"
        self.result_label.text = result_text

    def update_player_list(self):
        player_names = [player['name'] for player in self.data['players']]
        self.result_label.text = f"Available Players: {', '.join(player_names)}"

    def on_stop(self):
        self.save_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GolfScorecardApp().run()
```

Image from inside Kivy https://imgur.com/iinDAXR

Comment: Hi there, please add some more details to your question and some example code. You have provided very little information so it is practically impossible to help you.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can check your code. Thank you.